# Navigation bar displaying different on Mac versus my PC

Tags: html, macos

I am working on my first website, and one of my concerns at the moment is my navigation bar. It should display across from my name in the middle, however, it displays lower than my name every time I check the Macs at school. Someone said it could be the padding in my navigation causing the error? I've tried a few different things but I'm still having this problem.

I'm at a lost as to what the problem could be! I'd like to understand more how the website could work correctly on the pc's I've checked but not Macs. I'm slowly but surely learning all this, so any help is appreciated.

My site is

www.nmariephoto.com

Comment: Nicole, just a note: the display of your site depends on the browser the person is using, rather than whether it is a Mac or PC. For example, the Safari browser, Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Opera are all browsers that may render your content differently.

Comment: Hey, I've run all the browswers you mentioned on my pc and others without issues. It is when I run those browswers on Macs when I have issues...So are the browswers rendered differently on Macs then? Is there a way to fix this issue then?

Comment: @NicoleMarie On Mac, if you're using Safari or Google Chrome, it's the same engine, WebKit. But, Firefox on Mac or PC uses Gecko so it may changes rendering but not from a OS to another...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to declaring a left margin on the UL with #dd, you should zero out the other margins. The browser adds a "before" and "after" margin of 1em which is causing your problem.

So on line 134 of PortfolioStyles.css, change

```
margin-left: 12%;
```

to

```
margin: 0 0 0 12%;
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use of **reset.css** to avoid such issues it will reset all your style of every element, if you don't know then pls google it you will get lots of site from where you can find it. thanks